# Change status bar icons tint

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Lollipop we can change the color of status bar background or even make it transparent. Let's suppose I want a light background (#eee). Status bar icons' default color is white, so they would become illegible. Is it possible to make them dark?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @alanv, thanks. Are there any plans to change it or we're just not supposed to make light status bars?

Comment: How do you change the background? If you build Android from source, you can change the icon color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now possible in Android 6+ using this attr in `style.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```